# Spring Boot WebMvcTest does not reach the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm having an issue where my spring MVC test does not reach the controller with matching path.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TaskController.class)
public class TaskRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void givenTasks_whenGetTaskById_thenReturnJsonMap() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/task/{id}", "001").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


    @Test
    public void givenTasks_whenGetTasks_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/task").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The specific controller looks like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class TaskController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Arrays.asList(new Task(), new Task()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Task> getTaskById(@PathVariable String id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Task(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I continuously get a 404 response. And when debugging it doesn't hit the TaskController.

I left the repository and services involved in the controller for brevity and just return hardcoded new Task with status OK for the example.

I have also tried by removing the controller level RequestMapping and specifying the mapping explicitly on the @GetMappings... Also that didn't work out.

I'm using version **2.1.4.RELEASE** of the **spring-boot-*** dependencies.

Comment: My guess is that @AutoConfigureMockMvc is missing from the test class.

Comment: all is fine with your project, works as expected

Comment: You can check this here: https://github.com/mariuszs/task-controller-demo

Comment: Hmmm then I have to dive in, then it must be something else in my code blocking it from working, which I left here for brevity.

Comment: Have you solved your issue already?

Comment: unfortunately I do not recall if my team resolved the issue. @bvn13 I also can't check anymore as I left the company for pursuing a new challenge.

Comment: @Szellem AutoConfigureMockMvc is part/included of @ WebMvcTest